# any callbacks for disabled mui slider

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, slider

I have a disabled Material UI slider. If the user tries to change the slider I want to show a message to him like "this slider is disabled". But I did not found any callback which fires on a disabled slider.

```
<Slider disabled={true}

        {/* non of these callbacks are working */}
        onClick={()=>alert('disabled')}
        onTouchStart={()=>alert('disabled')}
        ...
/>
```

Another solution would be to not disable the slider but set a custom flag which is checked in the `onChange` callback and reset the slider to its initial state if the flag is set in addition to show the message. But this would be rather hacky and feels pretty laggy on a slow device.

Any ideas how to solve this?